# The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, biztalk-2016

I've got Biz Talk project in VSTS and I'm trying to build the project. Here is the error i face

```
Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
```

Please find my Build definition attached[image]

I find the stated targets file exists in my Local [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk]
Build Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Please help/suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the hosted agent, it looks like the hosted agent can't build BizTalk applications because it's missing the required build targets. There's no way around that; you'll have to set up your own build agent.

If this is on a build agent you control, it looks like you need to install the appropriate BizTalk references on your build agent.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I've Configured Local agent. I've installed Biztalk reference and my build succeeded.